# How to find journals that only require a PDF for their final submission?

Tags: journal-workflow

Almost all journals I have published so far have required either Word or LaTeX source files after acceptance (but with present-day OCR technology it is straightforward to generate Word or LaTeX files from a PDF). Thus, where and how to find journals that are content with just a PDF (or a link to a pre-print repository) for their final submission?

EDIT: The reason I am asking this is because a *.tex file can be compiled in different ways and what worked on creation, need not work at the production team's office. And the need to submit separate source graphics when it is already possible to embed it in a high-quality PDF seems superfluous.

Comment: There is a name for this class of journals.  No need to list all such journals, so this is not a shopping question.

Comment: "with present-day OCR technology, it is straightforward to generate Word or LaTeX files from a PDF." ha!!

Comment: Indeed, the OCR bit is not close to reality.  The question in the title is seems valid, however.

Comment: @TerryLoring - well, really? Nobody (well, almost nobody for sure) writes their paper directly as a PDF - it usually is written in Word or some TeX variant to begin with, so those files are available. Conference proceedings (camera ready copy) are the big counterexample, but those would not do any OCRing much less editing of the paper.

Comment: I'll at least reopen and let the community decide now that the post has been edited.

Comment: If you want your work to be taken seriously, I advise you to prepare it using LaTeX. See #1 here: https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=304

Comment: @TerryLoring why do you say the OCR technology is not close to reality? Software from Mathpix.com is quite good and much better than Adobe and MS-Word for equations.

Comment: If you can get a complex equation parsed by Mathpix.com, I would love to know.  Something like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5183/split-like-environment-inside-cases-environment

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to downvote this question, but this sounds very much like an XY problem to me. Are you sure the appropriate response to whatever problem you're experiencing isn't ensuring that your .tex file compiles correctly on all computers (e.g. by avoiding various non-standard packages) rather than looking for a journal which accepts pdf submissions?

Comment: @Cel I'm confused why anyone would ask this question. Why is this relevant to you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are journals called overlay journals.  All the formatting is done by the author which can be a lot of work. Anyhow, you can look on the web for overlay journals.

I have never heard of a journal that takes a PDF, reverse engineers a latex file and proceeds from there.  Simple equations perhaps can be dealt with, but OCR is going to have a hard time dealing with kappa vs k, double subscripts, commutative diagrams, that sort of thing.

Also, most authors do not know enough about color-space conversion to deal with images correctly.

I think there should be more overlay journals, but be aware these are not exactly friendly to authors.  You have to make it look good, and if you fail, whom are you to blame?

Added later:  The journal I am familiar with, SIGMA, seems to have changed how they work (or I just forgot).  I think they do fiddle with your latex file.
https://www.emis.de/journals/SIGMA/about.html

Comment: To get and idea of color profiles, read this. 
 If the journals is to be online only, this stuff gets easier. 
 Getting printed paper images and online images to mathc is a job for someone who is not me. https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/color-managing-documents.html

Comment: Thank you, for this great answer. Indeed, I wish there were more overlay journals too!

Comment: You still need to fiddle with a style file, most likely, but need only involve your computer and the arxiv computer.  There is one figure in my book that is blurry because the publishers computer could not handle the tex code.  One survives.

Comment: I think an overlay journal collects content from different sources and does not receive authors' contributions and manuscripts in their own formatting style.

Comment: @Younes To clarify:  you have to do the formatting; you don't get free reign to pick the format.  Edited to clarify that point.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? As far as I know (and Wikipedia [confirms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_journal)), an overlay journal is one that essentially just gives a "stamp of correctness" to submissions to a preprint server such as Arxiv. But even Arxiv will [reject your submission](https://arxiv.org/help/submit_pdf) in the first place if it's a pdf generated from tex without the corresponding source.

Comment: You have to use the style file, which means you have to use latex.  Of course, there may be non-latex overlay journals.  No idea how those might work.

Comment: @Federico Poloni  By my logic, an overlay journal is accepting a pdf submission, or at least a pointer to a pdf as submission.  Now you have to upload the latex file to the arxiv, but I think young academics assume they need to do that anyway.

Comment: @TerryLoring So what's the difference with respect to a "traditional" journal? You still need to submit a .tex.

Comment: In a tradition journal, the latex needs to run on the journal's system, and the journal will edit your latex file directly.  Thus you need to make your latex run in three environments.  On the overlay journal, you end up doing more of the work, but only need to deal with your system and the arvix.

Comment: @Federico Poloni  Of course, some journals don't use latex for the final product.  I think the OP did not live through submitting to math journals in the days before latex.  Overlay or not, the modern systems are a lot better.   (Now the referee report systems....)

Comment: @Federico Poloni Checking a journal website, I see I had it wrong, or that my answer was a bit dated.  Y'all can read about this overlay journal 'cause I added a link.

Comment: Remark: the journal Sigma mentioned here is not to be confused with [Forum of Mathematics: Sigma](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/forum-of-mathematics-sigma/information/author-instructions/submitting-your-materials).

Answer (score 11):

The premise of the question is triply false.

1. It is NOT trivial to convert technical documents to OCR in a systematic way.  OCR works for 99% of the regular text (enough for indexing and searching) but still struggles with small fonts, specialized fonts, indices and the placement of indices, and a lot of the technical stuff that goes into technical writing.
2. Many journals that accept .tex files have publicly available LaTeX templates, style files and packages that will produce local versions very close to the eventual published version.  All the journals I know also handle various external packages or are explicit about packages they do not handle.
3. Producing a pdf does not guarantee the published version will be identical to the submitted version.  Most editors have house rules to enforce some measure of uniformity between articles when it comes to referencing, figures, tables, and the labelling of them, abbreviations, or use special sets of fonts which inevitably lead to small changes between the final accepted version and the production version.  (Even overlay journals have house rules.)

Comment: To the user who raised Low Quality Post flag on this answer, please explain why. After reviewing this post, I see no problem at all. If you believe there is something wrong, please point it out.

Comment: I disagree with your point 2: in my experience, incompatible packages (amsthm, tikz, mathtools...), quirky syntax (author/institution, keywords) and spurious text (criminally false "copyright (c) 2001 someoneelse" lines) are still an annoyance, when one uses journal styles.